# iOS XMLParser - get url

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

I would like to parse an XML tag that looks something like this:

```
<image href="..."/>
```

I'm currently using `BlockRSSParser` to do it.

I've tried to do it in the following method:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{

    // String is empty: 

}
```

What is the correct way to parse XML like this using `XMLParser`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get attribute values in the `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` method:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
        NSString *href = attributes[@"href"];
    }
}
```